# Windows MAX/MIN macros as templates

Tags: c++, c++11

If I were to write the Windows min/max macros as template functions what would be the correct way of doing it?

The min macro is defined as:

```
#define min(a, b)  (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

I guess one alternative would be to do this:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename R = std::common_type_t<T, U>>
constexpr R min(T const& a, U const& b) {
    return std::min(static_cast<R>(a), static_cast<R>(b));
}
```

Would that be correct and/or have the exact same behavior?

std::min cannot be used since it expects both arguments to be of the same type.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min

Comment: Why did you [delete your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678770/windows-max-min-macros-as-templates), only to re-ask it a few minutes later?

Comment: _"std::min cannot be used since it expects both arguments to be of the same type."_ There's still template type deduction in place. Can you elaborate more why `std::min` _"can't be used"_ ? Provide a [MCVE] where that fails please.

Comment: "since it expects both arguments to be of the same type." There's a reason. A function can have one return type.

Comment: ^ @DeiDei Not to mention that this is also required for the ternary conditional operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming values `a` and `b` are arithmetic types, you could do:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto min(T a, U b) -> typename std::common_type<T, U>::type {
    // This is a lot cleaner in C++14 where we can use std::common_type_t and local
    // variables in a constexpr function. Alternatively, you could just implement
    // this by casting a and b to their common type and calling std::min.
    return static_cast<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type>(a) <
           static_cast<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type>(b) ?
           static_cast<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type>(a) :
           static_cast<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type>(b);
}
```

Note, however, that using this comes with the drawbacks of hiding the casts, and it is not obvious what the return type is. For example, mixing signed and unsigned arguments might result in bugs if you aren't careful and intentional.

In general, I would recomment just using `std::min` and casting the types as needed (e.g. if `a` is `int` and `b` is float, just do `std::min(static_cast<float>(a), b)`).

Comment: Can you not have `using common_t = typename std::common_type<T, U>::type;`?

Comment: @Justin: Yeah, `using` would be a good idea here. As for your updated code, that should work correctly and be just fine.

Comment: @Cornstalks would you have any idea why the template version generates shorter assembly? https://godbolt.org/g/42ipDX

Comment: @Mac It's interesting; the macro assembly has an instruction with reversed operands, then moves the result, whereas the template assembly operates directly on the result. I'm no assembly expert, but my best guess is that the template version gives the compiler type information for arguments, which might play with some floating point rules to make the optimization valid. Indeed, if you pass `-Ofast`, the compiler generates identical assembly, meaning that there is some floating point rule coming into play

Comment: @Mac: It's because `std::min` is implemented as `b < a ? b : a`, whereas your macro is `a < b ? a : b`. The difference between the two is significant for `NaN` values; otherwise they're identical. In the code in your link, only one of the original parameters can be `NaN`, which allows the optimizer to optimize the `std::min` code a little better. If you swap the parameters to `std::min`, you're function will match `std::min`'s code generate (to be more explicit: `std::min(a, b)` generates different code than `std::min(b, a)`).